# Run php on .htm files in plesk 11.5

Tags: apache, .htaccess, nginx, plesk

I am leasing a Unix (Ubuntu) virtual server.

It was recently compromised and so my ISP (WebFusion) removed all my sites and re-installed the server. It is my task to re-build all the websites it contained.

They replaced the old Plesk 9.4 with 11.5, and now I find .htaccess files are ignored, and so I must find another way to direct the server to push .htm files through PHP.

My test for this is done with two files called phpt.php and phpt.htm. Both contain simply

```
<?php echo "hello" ?>
```

The .php file works, but the .htm does not.

There is a place in the panels which seems designed to do this. In "Websites & Domains", if I click "Web Server Settings", I can see two areas where I can add "Additional directives".

The comments say I should use httpd.include syntax, and if I research that I see I can say things like "AddHandler cgi-script .cgi".
So I added "AddHandler php-script .htm" an also "AddHandler php5-script .htm", saved and restarted the server.

This doesn't work. Research suggests it's because nginx is now included with Apache and they interact in such a way as to break this. Great.

So I removed those directives and researched it some more and found this article http://kb.sp.parallels.com/en/115773 which says I should make a "conf" directory under the domain root and place a file in it called "vhost.conf" which should contain (for CGI application implementations of PHP like mine):

```
<Files ~ (\.html)>
    SetHandler None
    AddHandler php-script .html
    Options +ExecCGI
    allow from all
</Files>
```

I changed this to replace .html with .htm (removing the l) in both locations. I then restarted the server again, but it still doesn't work.

So at this point I'm at a loss and I would appreciate any help anyone might be able to offer.

Thanks, Chris

Comment: How does this question connect to nginx?

Comment: @AlexeyTen You can read that: [How To Configure Nginx as a Reverse Proxy for Apache](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-nginx-as-a-reverse-proxy-for-apache)

Comment: @Croises, and so what? _I know_ how to configure nginx. What I don't know, how this question connects to nginx

Comment: @AlexeyTen You can not use some Apache settings, because they do not work with nginx ...

Comment: @Croises none of Apache settings works with nginx. They works with Apache. But my telepathy tells me that nginx's config contains something like `location ~ .php` and nginx serves html files as is instead of passing them to Apache

Comment: Alexey, I think your link is what I need, however, I do not have the expertise to safely execute all those instructions.

I find it hard to beleve that something which was so easy in Plesk 9.4 is to difficult in Plesk 11.5. Isn't there an easier way? At this point, I'm considering changing all internal ,htm URLs on my website to .php as a miserble fallback.

Comment: @AlexeyTen Nginx work after Apache, and some Apache settings that work well without Nginx, do not work with.

Comment: @Croises What do you mean by "Nginx works after Apache"? Does browsers connects to Apache? Or Nginx? Or something else?

Comment: @AlexeyTen Plesk can use Nginx as Reverse Proxy for Apache. All connections are made to Apache via Nginx.

Comment: So here nginx is _before_ apache (as seen from browser). That means @ChrisWesley should show nginx config.

Answer (score 1):

Go to "Web Server Settings" on your domain.

Try to remove html and htm files from "Serve static files directly by nginx" or disable this setting.

[image: Web Server Settings]

Answer (score 0):

I use that in my root `.htaccess` with Plesk 12.0.18 (also with Apache and nginx):

```
AddHandler php-script .htm
```

That was ok with Plesk 11 (but not with 9...)

Comment: Croises, thank you for your contribution but I cannot understand what you are saying. Are you saying you put the AddHandler directive in .htacess at the root of your domain (at the same level as the httpdocs folder) and it works?

Comment: Not at the same level, but in the `httpdocs` folder. And yes, that work well for me, since years.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is depressing. All of the stuff I read about nginx not passing directives to Apache is apparently not true. The Parallels article is also un-necessary. Michael - there is no option like the one you mentioned.

The fields provided by Plesk for "additional directives" DO work, but I had the syntax wrong. I added exactly and only this to the "custom value" for the "Handlers" field:

php-script .php .htm

It works. Before I had a variety of erroneous versions of this - sometimes including "AddHandler" sometimes including "php5" and sometimes including multiple lines with different file types.

But this works. No restart required.

Thanks for all who tried to help me. I hope this will help others.

Now on to the next migration nightmare.